# How to know which Python modules do not need to be imported?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-module

I am tidying up my project's `virtualenv requirements.txt`, and want to make sure all required packages are included. I get errors when importing `json` and `hashlib`, until I realize those modules are already included in Python 3.6

Are there any ways to find out if `import`ed modules are part of the shipped Python module and I don't need to install via `pip`?

Comment: 1 way is:
-> Uninstall all the packages in requirements.txt
-> run `pip freeze`
-> Install Again
-> rerun `pip freeze`
-> Take the diff

Answer (score 0):

You can test your `requirements.txt` file against clean Python installation in the following way:

```
requirements = [r.split('=')[0] for r in open('requirements.txt').readlines()]

for r in requirements:
    r = r.replace('-', '_')
    try:
        exec('import {}'.format(r.lower()))
    except ImportError:
        try:
            exec('import {}'.format(r.upper()))
        except ImportError:
            try:
                exec('import {}'.format(r.capitalize()))
            except ImportError:
                print('{} is not a built-in module'.format(r))
```

Not the prettiest code I wrote but it gets the job done ;)